# Select row with most recent timestamp

Tags: mysql, sorting

Actually my database consists of two main tables cities & weather and I want to select the most recent entry of the weather table.

It looks approximately like this:

```
plz     cities_plz description name         modified
9020      9020     looks great Klagenfurt   24.04.2017
9020      9020     rain        Klagenfurt   25.04.2017
9020      9020     rain        Klagenfurt   10.04.2017
9100      9100     sunny       Villach      25.04.2017
```

So now, I just want to get the latest entry. I tried it already with this command:

```
select   * 
from     weather, cities 
WHERE    weather.cities_plz = cities.plz 
ORDER BY modfified DESC;
```

The problem is, that this cmd didn't drop the dublicates...
Any ideas? Would appreciate it!

Comment: Show us the other table as well. Does the two tables contain `modified`?

Comment: Duplicates of which field?

Comment: We stopped writing queries in this way in 1992. Come. Join us. Also, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LIMIT` to get the last modified entry:

```
SELECT * 
FROM weather, cities 
WHERE weather.cities_plz = cities.plz
ORDER BY modified DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

You want the last entry for each city:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM weather, cities 
WHERE weather.cities_plz = cities.plz
    AND modified = (SELECT MAX(modified) FROM weather WHERE weather.cities_plz = plz)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `weather`, `cities` WHERE `weather`.`cities_plz` = `cities`.`plz`
AND `modified` = (SELECT MAX(modified) FROM `weather` WHERE `cities_plz` = `cities_plz`) ORDER BY `modified` DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write sub query for this

```
SELECT test.* FROM  
(select * from weather LEFT JOIN cities on cities.plz = weather.cities_plz 
ORDER BY weather.modified DESC) as test 
GROUP BY test.cities_plz
```